# Will the next Windows Server support .NET 2.0?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-server-2008

My team developed hundreds of applications and modules using the .NET 2.0 Framework. This was supported by Windows Server 2003, and Windows Server 2008 (which actually supports mixed pools of frameworks).

Will Microsoft stop supporting .NET 2.0 in the next version of Windows Server?

Comment: You're not running 2.0 if you're running on server 2008.  That's 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for .NET 2.0 is [slated to be discontinued on 4/12/2011](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-us&x=18&y=12&p1=8291), and extended support  will be discontinued in on 4/12/2016.  If they don't extend it.

They also released a press release on this topic titled "[Microsoft .NET Framework Support Lifecycle Policy](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifeandotnet)".

The difference between mainstream support and extended support [is outlined here](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifepolicy).

So .NET will probably *physically run* on future servers, but there won't be support if something goes wrong.

Comment: @ George: what is the difference between main stream and extended